# How to continuously check the status of a serial port in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, serial-port

I am currently using a `SerialPort` class, but would also like to have a status of the port (present/not present) within my WPF app in order to check if the card-reader is disconnected physically.

Is there a way to do it in .NET?

The code I use is following

```
public class Proxi
    {
        public string proxicard = "";
        public DateTime readingtime = DateTime.MinValue;
        public bool Ready = false;
        public bool Correct = false;
        public bool COMreader = false;
        public bool COMAccess = false;
        public bool COMDataCorrect = false;
        public MemoryStream COMdata = new MemoryStream();
        public SerialPort port;

        // Public Event to allow other classes to subscribe to.
        public event EventHandler CardDetected = delegate { };

        public Proxi(string portname, bool isCOM)
        {
            try
            {
                port = new SerialPort(portname, 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One)
                {
                    DtrEnable = true,
                    RtsEnable = true
                };
                port.Open();
                port.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(Port_DataReceived);
                Ready = true;
                COMreader = isCOM;
            }
            catch
            {
                proxicard = "There is no port " + portname;
            }
        }

        private void Port_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            SerialPort serialPort = (SerialPort)sender;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[serialPort.BytesToRead];
            serialPort.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            proxicard = "";

            if ((int)buffer[0] == 58 && !COMreader)
            {
                for (int index = 1; index < buffer.Length; ++index)
                    proxicard = proxicard + ((char)buffer[index]).ToString();

                if (proxicard.Length >= 12)
                {
                    byte[] numArray = ConvertHexToByte(proxicard, 6);
                    byte num = 0;
                    for (int index = 0; index < numArray.Length - 1; ++index)
                        num += numArray[index];
                    Correct = (int)(byte)((uint)~num + 1U) == (int)numArray[numArray.Length - 1];
                    readingtime = DateTime.Now;
                }
                else
                    Correct = false;
            }
            if ((int)buffer[0] == 1 && COMreader)
            {
                COMdata = new MemoryStream();
                COMAccess = true;
                if (buffer.Length > 1)
                    COMdata.Write(buffer, 1, buffer.Length - 1);
            }

            if (!COMAccess || !COMreader || COMdata.Length < 7L)
            {

                // Raise Event, which triggers all method subscribed to it!
                CardDetected(this, new EventArgs());

                return;
            }

            MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
            memoryStream.Write(new byte[1] { (byte)1 }, 0, 1);
            for (int offset = (int)COMdata.Length - 2; offset >= 0; --offset)
                memoryStream.Write(COMdata.ToArray(), offset, 1);
            Correct = (int)CRC.CRC8(memoryStream.ToArray(), (int)memoryStream.Length) == (int)COMdata.ToArray()[COMdata.Length - 1L];
            proxicard = Proxi.GetRecordHEXBytes(COMdata.ToArray(), 1, 5);
            COMdata = new MemoryStream();
            COMAccess = false;

            // Raise Event, which triggers all method subscribed to it!
            CardDetected(this, new EventArgs());
        }

        public static string GetRecordHEXBytes(byte[] data, int position, int length)
        {
            if (position + length > data.Length)
                return "";
            string str = "";
            for (int index = 0; index < length; ++index)
            {
                byte num = data[position + index];
                str += num.ToString("X2");
            }
            return str;
        }

        public byte[] ConvertHexToByte(string HexValue, int length)
        {
            byte[] numArray = new byte[length];
            for (int index = 0; index < length; ++index)
                numArray[index] = (byte)Convert.ToChar(Convert.ToUInt32(HexValue.Substring(index * 2, 2), 16));
            return numArray;
        }

        public void Close()
        {
            port.Close();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two conditions to be met to consider reader is connected:

1. COM port is successfuly open
2. Some test communication is performed. This can be two-way communication (you ask reader for something, e.g. version) or if the reader communicates on regular basis and sends every several seconds some test data, you can wait for those.

Please also keep in mind if only condition 1 is met then it means absolutely nothing for reader presence detection. If user sets up the communication port to be the port number that is always present (e.g. non-USB device) then opening of such a port succeeds even if there is nothing connected.

And note handling only Receive event is probably not enough because depending on communication protocol no data may be received at all even if the reader is connected.

For continuous detection you probably want to create a thread that will regularly try to open serial port and perform some test communication with the reader. If all of that succeeds you just change some bool variable (e.g. `IsConnected`) in model class that indicates the reader is connected. On the view side you should bind some control content to the `IsConnected` flag.